# Why am I getting several Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in errors after moving Joomla 2.5 site to new webhost?

Tags: migration, joomla2.5

I have a website built on Joomla 2.5.9 that I moved from my development server 
to my client's hosting account on GoDaddy. All of the files have been uploaded, 
the database created, the contents of the development server database has been 
imported and the configuration.php file has been updated.

Here is the site on my development server:

http://digitaldemo.net/anova/

and on my client's GoDaddy account:

http://scientific-practices.com/demo/

Instead of the site coming up, all I get are the following errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/libraries/joomla/access/access.php on line 409

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/libraries/joomla/application/menu.php on line 63

Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/includes/router.php on line 221

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/includes/router.php on line 227

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/includes/application.php on line 465

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/content/27/10688727/html/booksite/demo/templates/beez_20/error.php on line 10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

i think this issue for php version / mysql version problem

please check.